# jquery messagebox get from button click mvc4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

[when i click to the button it is not opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcXdB.png)

Popup

This is test Popup for Applicaiton Tab

Comment: it,s a little code i match the tutorial each word infect alphabets but it is not running neither error or exception plz help me ...

Comment: Please paste the code in your question rather than an image of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `opener` click event you have not added the `#` before `dialog-model`. The click event should like below.

```
$('#opener').click(function(){
  $ ("#dialog-model").dialog('open');
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/6tvoma2c/

Comment: Yes Thank you so much